# Optimality in Hierarchy of Machines (HAM Framework)

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning

How is it that the HAM framework provides the Hierarchically Optimal solution while the MAXQ framework provides the recursively optimal solution?

The above statement is based on Section `4.3` [here](http:///media/ameet/8AD2C89ED2C88FBD/Books%20and%20Documents/Academics/IIT/IIT%20Material/Sem%206/Reinforcement%20Learning/ResearchPapers/) and Section `2` [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.08869.pdf).

The following are the quotes respectively.

1. SMDP DP or RL methods applied to HAMs, or to MDPs with options whose
   policies are fixed apriori, yield hierarchically optimal policies
2. Using HAMQ learning [10], HAM can also converge
   to a hierarchical optimal solution

Answer (score 2):

Due to the sub-tasks using a projected value function that may detract from the overall objective being optimised, MAX-Q is recursively optimal.

HAMs do no such projection and work directly on the reward signal, hence they optimise the overall objective (with the hierarchy assumptions provided by the state machines) and are hierarchically optimal.